# Profile is not added in Audience Manager from DXA

Tags: dxa, audience-manager, dxa-1.6

We are using SDL Web 8.5 and DXA 1.6. We are trying to create profile from our website which needs to be saved in Audience Manager. We have our code written in DXA (.Net) to create/update profile in Audience Manager and we are using: `Tridion.OutboundEmail.ContentDelivery.Profile`

The problem is when we create/update profile, it stays for 2-3 days (i.e. when we go to our website we can see our new/updated profile information). After that, the profile information doesn't show on website. We also noticed that in Tridion Audience Manager section we don't see that profile information added that we created from website.
Can anyone please tell me if any configuration changes are missing which is why the profile is not being saved properly?

Comment: Are you using the DXA Audience Manager Module?

Comment: How to check that?

Comment: If you don't know, I guess the answer is "no". :-)   Check if there is a DLL called  `Sdl.Web.Modules.AudienceManager.dll` in the `bin` Folder  (and/or an `Area` named `AudienceManager`).

Comment: If you're not using it yet: consider doing so.

Comment: I thought SDL Web 8.5 goes with DXA 1.7 to at least DXA 2.0. Not sure if 1.6 is an issue, but Frank Taylor mentioned [problems with Audience Manager contacts with DXA 1.6 and CIL 8.3 in this post](http://blog.frankmtaylor.com/2018/03/27/dxa-1-6-and-audience-manager/). Technically the post should be a Trex question.

Comment: Are you saying that the new Contact shows up on your website AND within the Tridion Content Manager Explorer -- but then disappears after a few days?